# Blazor WebAssembly - Write to IDE console from server side controller method

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm taking my first steps in moving to Blazor development, coming from MVC. For testing purposes I created a controller with the following method:

```
[Route("/server/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataContext _db;

    public HomeController(DataContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var q = from v in _db.MyTable select v;

        foreach(var v in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{v.Id}: {v.Description}");
        }


        return View();
    }
}
```

In my Visual Studio console, I have no output.
While in the foreach loop, in the "Locals" pane, I see these two values changing on each iteration:

```
Name                                           Value        Type
MySol.Shared.MyTable.Description.get returned  "DESC 1"     string
string.Format returned                         "1: DESC 1"  string
```

These values are removed from the "Locals" pane as soon as I exit the foreach loop.

Is there a way to write to console the usual way from server methods?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you expect to see the output?

Comment: Blazor is React#. It has *browser-side* components that may or may not call some HTTP services, written in any language or framework. A Blazor application doesn't have controllers. What you posted is a *server-side* controller that writes to the server's standard output. Neither Blazor WASM nor Blazor Server are involved

Comment: Blazor WASM solution template consists of 3 projects: _client side_, _server side_ and _shared_. The _server side_ part has controllers that are supposed to provide data to the _client side_ app (that runs on browser). When debugging client side project the browser console can be used. I was looking for a way to inspect some data in the server side project. I found that instead of Console.WriteLine() I have to use System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline().

Comment: The Output window has a combobox for the source it shows.